# vue-test-utils: could not overwrite property $route, this is usually caused by a plugin that has added the property as a read-only value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I've looked at other answers with this problem, and it seems to be caused by trying to import `vue-router` into the test. This however, is not the case for my problem. Here is my test code:

```
import { mount, shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import ListDetails from '../components/homepage/ListDetails'
import EntityList from '../components/homepage/EntityList'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import faker from 'faker'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(BootstrapVue)

describe('ListDetails.vue', () => {
    it('gets the correct page list when router list id param present', () => {
        const selected_list = {
            id: faker.random.number(),
            name: faker.lorem.words(),
            entries: []
        }

        testRouteListIdParam(selected_list)
    })
})
```

Then in `testRouteListIdParam`, I have:

```
function testRouteListIdParam(selected_list) {
    // just assume this sets up a mocked store properly.
    const store = setUpStore(selected_list, true)

    const $route = {
        path: `/homepage/lists/${selected_list.id}`
    }

    const wrapper = mount(ListDetails, {
        mocks: {
            $route
        },
        store,
        localVue
    })
}
```

As soon as `mount()` happens, I get the error:

```
[vue-test-utils]: could not overwrite property $route, this is usually caused by a plugin that has added the property as a read-only value
```

Any ideas why this would be happening? Again, I'm not using VueRouter anywhere in the unit tests, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Could it be BootstrapVue or Vuex that are messing things up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So this is a bug with vue-test-utils. If you are using VueRouter *anywhere* (even if it's not used in any unit test), you will get the above error.

A work around is to use process.env.NODE_ENV in your unit tests and set it to 'test', and wherever you're using VueRouter, check process.env.NODE_ENV like so:

```
if (!process || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    Vue.use(VueRouter)
}
```

at least until vue-test-utils bug is fixed, this should fix this problem

Comment: I don't think this is true, and I'm not able to reproduce it with a Vue CLI project. I was only able to reproduce the bug when installing VueRouter from a component's code path, which brings it into the unit test. Can you provide a link to a GitHub repo that reproduces the problem? I might be able to pinpoint it for you.

Comment: yeah, i have it reproducible at this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/oxvvn2r96 if you run the one test suite there it will pass since $route is undefined, and console will output that $route cannot be modified as it's read only

Comment: The error seems unique to that Codesandbox environment. See my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-router-mock-demo) that shows `$route` can be mocked without error.

Comment: The issue has to do with importing the router file in any test. Here's an example of that shows the failure: https://github.com/blimmer/vue-router-mock-demo/commit/ed1246db9121a70c6ae0d4c220286b55ae800e4c . For us, we import the router in order to test global navigation guards.

Answer (score 13):

I think these [docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vue-router.html#common-gotchas) are relevant to your situation:

> #### Common gotchas
>
> Installing Vue Router adds `$route` and `$router` as read-only properties on Vue prototype.
>
> This means any future tests that try to mock `$route` or `$router` will fail.
>
> To avoid this, never install Vue Router globally when you're running tests; use a `localVue` as detailed above.

The error you're seeing indicates that one of your components (and outside your test code) is installing VueRouter (e.g., `Vue.use(VueRouter)`).

To address the issue, search for the VueRouter installation in your component code path, including any of their imports, and refactor it so that the import is not required there. Typically, the installation of VueRouter exists only in `main.js` or its imports.

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-router-mock-demo)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this, and it was because I was importing `vueRouter` into a controller, outside of a vueComponent, where `this.$router` wasn't defined.

```
import router from '@/router';
router.push('/foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

[janedoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55544303/8186898) can work but it's often risky to modify production code just to make some tests pass. I prefer to bypass the bug by doing this:

1. Run your test in watch mode

   ```bash
   npx jest --watch src/components/Foo.test.ts
   ```
2. Locate `Vue.use(VueRouter)` in your code and diagnose what is the chain of components indirectly running the code by adding this just above

   ```
   const error = new Error();
   console.log(
     error.stack
       ?.split('\n')
       .filter((line) => line.includes('.vue'))
       .join('\n'),
   );
   ```

   This logs a list of file path like

   ```
   console.log
   at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/components/Bar.vue:1:1)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/components/Foo.vue:1:1)
   ```
3. Chose a component in this list and, in your test file, mock it

   ```
   jest.mock('/path/to/components/Bar.vue');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As I got this error with $bvModal from bootstrap-vue and came across this page, I will post my solution here which might be helpful for anyone getting this error for read-only properties.

First of all, the reason as it is mentioned in other answers is that you register a component or plugin which has a read-only property, therefore you cannot mock it anymore. So the problem is only mocking it not the code itself and I'd rather not change the code.

***I removed it from mocks and mocked it after mounting.***

in my case we had this:

```
mockOptions = {
  propsData: mockProps,
  mocks: {
    $store: store,
    $route,
    $bvModal: {
      show: jest.fn(),
      hide: jest.fn(),
    },
  },
  localVue,
};

const wrapper = mount(ActionModals, mockOptions);         
expect(mockOptions.mocks.$bvModal.hide).toHaveBeenCalledWith('editItemModal');
```

I changed it to this:

```
mockOptions = {
  propsData: mockProps,
  mocks: {
    $store: store,
    $route,
  },
  localVue,
};

const wrapper = mount(ActionModals, mockOptions);  
jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.$bvModal, 'hide').mockImplementation(jest.fn());       
expect(wrapper.vm.$bvModal.hide).toHaveBeenCalledWith('editItemModal');
```

Therefore for the route, ***if you have to register it***, **mock it after mounting**.